# How to convert all columns in Pandas DataFrame to 'object' while ignoring NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe for which I want every column to be in string format. So I do this:

```
 df = df.astype(str)
```

The problem is that in this way all the NaN entries are converted to string 'nan'. And `isnull` returns `false`. Is there a way to convert to string but keep empty entry as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Series you can use `astype` on the part only which is `notnull` without need to re-replace the `NaN`s

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, np.nan, 'String'])
df[df.notnull()] = df[df.notnull()].astype(str)
```

As remarked in the comments, for a DataFrame you can use

```
df.where(df.isna(), df.astype(str))
```

Comment: This only works with one column, else you get `TypeError`. You'd instead need `df.where(~df.notnull(), df.astype('str'))` to generalize it. +1 for the good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it suits my purpose better. I tried it without `df.where` and it works fine.

Answer (score 9):

When you do `astype(str)`, the dtype is always going to be `object`, which is a dtype that includes mixed columns. Therefore, one thing you can do is convert it to `object` using `astype(str)`, as you were doing, but then replace the `nan` with actual `NaN` (which is inherently a float), allowing you to access it with methods such as `isnull`:

```
df.astype(str).replace('nan',np.nan)
```

**Example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['x',2,np.nan,'z']})
>>> df
  col1
0    x
1    2
2  NaN
3    z

# Note the mixed str, int and null values:
>>> df.values
array([['x'],
       [2],
       [nan],
       ['z']], dtype=object)

df2 = df.astype(str).replace('nan',np.nan)

# Note that now you have only strings and null values:
>>> df2.values
array([['x'],
       ['2'],
       [nan],
       ['z']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 6):

Convert your null values to empty strings, then cast the dataframe as string type.

```
df.replace(np.nan, '').astype(str)
```

Note that you could test for 'nulls' via:

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.str.len() == 0)
```